# Associating a reply with a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a very basic forum-like app, where Users can create Topics and reply to existing Topics.

The Topic creation works fine and I'm able to display Reply form, however, the Reply create action is not working properly. I don't have any errors, it just `redirects_to topics_path`.

This is following a tutorial, so the code is not mine. Is anyone able to spot the obvious cause for this? Any help much appreciated!

---

replies_controller.rb

```
def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @reply = @topic.replies.create(params[:reply].permit(:reply))
    @reply.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    @reply.save

    if @reply.save
        redirect_to topic_path(@topic)
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Error."
        redirect_to topics_path
    end
end
```

---

reply.rb

```
class Reply < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

replies/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @topic.replies.create] do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :reply %>
    <%= f.text_area :reply, class: "textarea", rows: "10" %>

    <%= f.submit class: "button is-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

---

topic.rb

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :replies
end
```

---

schema.rb

```
create_table "topics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
end

create_table "replies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "reply"
    t.bigint "topic_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["topic_id"], name: "index_replies_on_topic_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_replies_on_user_id"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In file **replies/_form.html.erb**
you should use build method `build` instead of `create`. Replace line:

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @topic.replies.create] do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @topic.replies.build] do |f| %>
```

There are some another problems with the code:

```
@reply = @topic.replies.create(params[:reply].permit(:reply))
```

In this line you call `new + save`, without user, which is required.
Change this to:

```
@reply = @topic.replies.new(params[:reply].permit(:reply))
```

Then, you call `save` twice:

```
@reply.save

    if @reply.save
...
```

First line is unnecessary.

And finally, what is the cause of rollback, in your Reply model you have:

```
belongs_to :post
```

But in the schema.rb and in the params you have `topic`:

**Schema.rb**:

```
t.bigint "topic_id"
```

**Params**:

```
"reply"=>{"reply"=>"Test reply"}, "commit"=>"Create Reply", "topic_id"=>"4"}
```

Comment: What are you receiving in the log after call the action?